# call c program from other c program in ILE C (AS/400 C)

Tags: c, ibm-midrange

I need to call a compiled c program, from a c program in AS/400 passing arguments by reference. I began by trying this code in as/400 that should call a program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
 
int main(void) {
  char *programName = "ls";
  char *arg1 = "-lh";
  char *arg2 = "/home";
 
  execlp(programName, programName, arg1, arg2, NULL);
 
  return 0;
}
```

which works in linux, but as400 doesn't recognize "execlp".

In COBOL I can easily call a C compiled program passing arguments by reference, which I need, like this:

```
 CALL "MYPROGRAM" USING BY REFERENCE ARG1, ARG2.
```

I thought of using system(), but I could not pass a variable by reference.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does your libc have POSIX's popen()?

Comment: no :/ I believe it only has this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=functions-fopen-open-files

Comment: Wow the docs - that's a restrictive runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `#pragma` to define the program name as uppercase and set the linkage to `OS`

```
#include <decimal.h>  

// -------------------- qcmdexc -------------------------------
#pragma map( qcmdexc, "QCMDEXC" )                              
#pragma linkage( qcmdexc, OS )                                 
void qcmdexc( char[], decimal(15,5)) ;                              

decimal(15,5) x = 30d ;    
char        cmds[256] ;  

// dlyjob 5 seconds                                        
strcpy( cmds, "dlyjob dly(5)                         " ) ; 
qcmdexc( cmds, x ) ;
```

should not matter that the program you are calling is a C program.  All ILE programs have the same interface.

Comment: I was trying with this example https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=icecocrpficp-programming-tasks  something similar, but in C they don't use the linkage line to consume cobol, and it wasn't working, thanks a lot!!!!